# Flutter 3.0 upgrade broke iterable extensions

Tags: flutter, iterable

After upgrading to flutter 3.0 it seems that the IterableExtension and the IterableIterableExtension of the collections.dart official API doc do not work anymore. Do you have to import a package manually to continue using them?

I'm particularly interested in flattened property of the IterableIterableExtension and in the sortedBy of the IterableExtension

Comment: Could you provide a piece of code that worked prior to 3.0 but has errors now?

Comment: I am not sure how it was used before, but there seems to be a package for collection -> [https://pub.dev/packages/collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection)

Comment: Are you using `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`, or are you expecting Flutter to export it?

Comment: Ok, thanks @jamesdlin you are right... Prior to 3.0 it was exported by flutter or some of my other imports. That is no longer the case and I need to import it explicitly. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll post the answer myself. immadisairaj  posted the link to the package I was talking about.

Comment: I'm skeptical that it worked before without explicitly importing `package:collection`.  I've tried using `.flattened` with Flutter 2.5.3 and Flutter 2.8.1, and they both are unrecognized.  I also do not see any `export` statements in the Flutter SDK from either version that would export `package:collection`'s symbols.  If it actually worked for you before, then maybe it was a side-effect from some other library you imported.

Comment: @jamesdlin yes . I digged it in. I was using freezed annotation library whose exports included the collection library. Their new version changed that to a simple import. When I updated to flutter 3.0 I also updated to the new freezed library. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer was given by [@jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin) as a comment below the question. I'm just reposting it as an answer, so nobody misses the solution when skimming over this question.

We experienced the same, but couldn't find a quick solution to this. I'm posting my error message here, so it can be found using search engines:

```
"error: The method 'whereNot' isn't defined for the type 'List'."
```

Solution is:

> I am not sure how it was used before, but there seems to be a [package for collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) ([@immadisairaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10136829/immadisairaj))
>
> Are you using `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';` ([@jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin))
>
> Prior to 3.0 it was exported by flutter or some of my other imports. That is no longer the case and I need to import it explicitly. ([@gbaccetta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5292951/gbaccetta))

If you haven't already: You should also add the package to your pubspec.yaml file, see this [linter rule](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/depend_on_referenced_packages.html).

We use the [freezed package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) and this is the only package that has a dependency on the collection package mentioned above. Probably changes between version 1.1.1 and version 2.1.0+1 of the package changed something (They do mention breaking changes, even though it was not clear to me, that this error was coming from the dependency upgrade.)

Btw: It was not clear to me, that the collection package has to be imported and is a pub.dev hosted package, as its docs can be found on [official flutter sites](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/whereNot.html).